# Extra Resources Created In Azure For VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

When I create a VM in Azure, it is creating an accompanying Cloud Service and Network Resource. I found that the Cloud Service is there as a deployment layer. I have not found why the Network Interface is there.

Since this particular circumstance is not going to have a deployment associated with it as it is used as an Elasticsearch server, I technically will not be needing the Cloud Service. However, when I delete the service, it takes the VM with it even though I do not expressly select it for delete.

My two specific questions:
1st - Why is there a Cloud Service created and not able to be deleted without repercussions when there is not deployment necessary?
2nd - Why is the Network Interface created and not able to be deleted without repercussions?

Both questions are with the understanding that this is an Elasticsearch VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cloud service is a required artefact of an ASM/classic deployment if a VM. It is not needed in an Azure Resource Manager deployment, which is what you should use for new deployments. However, the two types of deployment are orthogonal, so you may need to keep using ASM if you already have VMs deployed that way. If so, you should consider migrating them to ARM.

Comment: Thanks for that! We have deployed classic VM's and after your advice and additional education, it makes much more sense. Thanks again for the reply.